# How to deal with missing values in the output for XGBoost Regressor

Tags: scikit-learn, xgboost, data-science-model, xgboost-predict

So I am trying to create a regression model that takes two arrays as the input features and an array as an Output. However, some of the point in this dataset do not contain any value.
This is because I am taking a .tiff file of a city and converting all the values to an array. So any datapoints that lie outside the boundary of the city get initialised to an -3.4E+38.

For the input, I am just assigning the value for the null point = 9999 and setting the 'missing' parameter in my XGBoost Regressor = 9999.

`xgb_model = xgb.XGBRegressor(objective= "reg:squarederror", missing = 9999, eval_metric = "mae", n_estimators = 10000)`

But that only deals with the inputs containing a null point.

My output array also has some null points, but I am not sure how I should make it so that XGBoost considers those as null data points and not part of the required output?

What is happening is that since their is a fair bit of null points, the model gets biased and it skews the values of the output to the null value(9999).